# Is there a generic way to forward constructor arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, clone

I have a working `Cloneable/CloneableImpl` class pair below.  It does its job as long as I have default constructors from child to parent.

Suppose Animal's constructor is modified to `Animal( std::string const& name )`, which needs the name to be passed up from the children class constructors.

*How can I incorporate this requirement into the structure while keeping `Cloneable/CloneableImpl` generic?*

**In other words, I need to be able forward all constructor arguments from Lion, Tiger up to Animal.  Is there a way to do this in C++11 in a generic manner?**

If it's not possible, how can these templates be restructured to remain generic while allowing for the constructor requirement?

**Code**

```
template<typename P>
struct Cloneable
{
    virtual P* clone() const = 0;
};

template<typename T,typename P>
struct CloneableImpl :
    public P
{
    virtual P* clone() const 
    {
        return new T( dynamic_cast<T const&>(*this));
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Animal :
    public Cloneable<Animal>
{ 
};

struct Lion  : 
    public CloneableImpl<Lion,Animal> 
{ 
};

struct Tiger : 
    public CloneableImpl<Tiger,Animal> 
{ 
};

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    Animal* x = new Lion;
    Animal* y = x->clone();

    // we want to do this without hard-coding in template classes
    // Animal* z = new Lion( "Samba" );  
}
```

Comment: Sounds like inherited constructors. Not many compilers implement them yet though. Emulating them with a perfectly forwarding solution is tricky to get absolutely right and absolutely general.

Comment: What's wrong with ordinary C++11 perfect forwarding, *for the case at hand*?

Comment: You can write a 90%-use-case solution quickly, but to get it perfect there are various corner cases to consider (like forwarding `initializer_lists`, or explicit constructors, or maybe others; inheriting ctors get all of those right). You also need to be careful about copy constructors (http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html)... Personally I have been working with a 90% solution and endlessly delaying thinking really hard about it because it seems painful :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following @Cheersandhth.-Alf and @R. Martinho Fernandes' suggestions in the Comments to the OP to look into **perfect forwarding**.  I researched a bit and came up with this, which seems to work.

Thanks guys!

**CODE**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename P>
struct Cloneable
{
    virtual P* clone() const = 0;
};

template<typename T,typename P>
struct CloneableImpl :
    public P
{
    template<typename... Args>
    CloneableImpl( Args&&... args ) 
       : P(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {  }

    virtual P* clone() const 
    {
        return new T( dynamic_cast<T const&>(*this));
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Animal :
    public Cloneable<Animal>
{ 
    Animal( std::string const& name ) : m_name( name ) { }

    std::string  m_name;
};

struct Lion  : 
    public CloneableImpl<Lion,Animal> 
{ 
    template<typename... Args>
    Lion( Args&&... args ) 
       : CloneableImpl<Lion,Animal>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {  }
};

struct Tiger : 
    public CloneableImpl<Tiger,Animal> 
{ 
};

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    Animal* x = new Lion( "Samba" );
    Animal* y = x->clone();

    std::cerr << y->m_name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf a small, but great hint goes a long ways, especially in an evolving non-trivial language that is C++ - I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why not `virtual T* clone() const` ?  C++ allows return-type covariance.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `is_constructible<Lion, int>` is true, but shouldn't be because `is_constructible<Animal, int>` is not. You can fix that with constraints on the forwarding constructors, but it gets much uglier, and still gets corner-cases wrong, which is why it's not a 100% solution.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: with current compilers (as of Jan 2013) `is_constructible` isn't very reliable for standard library types, like `std::tuple`. having it work well for user defined types seems a bit of overkill then. better wait for that...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, could you explain what you mean? It works for my compiler.  For a simpler example, `is_default_constructible<Lion>` is true but `is_default_constructible<Animal>` is false, and I don't know of any problems with `is_default_constructible`.

Comment: uhm, it's late, and lots of distractions. maybe i meant `is_assignable`. i would have to check when it's less noise around.

Comment: so cool, helps me.